# Why can I still cast votes for on hold questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, voting

When a question is put `On Hold` users can still cast up or down votes. In *very rare* cases are these up votes. Most often they are down votes.

Since the question is closed, it seems like "piling on" negativity to allow users to cast down votes when the user already isn't going to get answers.

Is there a reason `On Hold` questions can still be voted on?

Comment: I suppose if they get a lot of upvotes it's a sign that the community likes the question. Additional upvotes or downvotes should help with further decision making if it's needed.

Comment: Well the reopen link is for pseudo "up" votes after it's closed. Just seems mean to allow down votes to pile on.

Comment: I agree, but I can't think of any viable way to fix it besides nurturing a site culture where users make 'educated/informed' votes. With specific reasons that we've discussed in chat over time, it may be possible to encourage better attitudes towards voting.

Comment: It could be fixed the same way you can't answer closed questions. Disallow all votes once a question is on hold.

Comment: I can actually say I appreciate it from experience. One of my recent qs went to -4 before being closed. It was nice to see that one person appreciated the discussion when it changed to -3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm having some serious déjà vu here - I could have *sworn* I just answered this. Turns out I did, a couple weeks back, [on a different site](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1868/791).

Reposted for convenience:

> There's background [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83798/165581).
>
> In an ideal situation, question closure is a temporary state. Either the closed question will be improved and reopened, or it will get deleted.
>
> If the question is reopened, that's great! The asker deserves whatever rep changes come along with the votes -- even the ones from when it was closed. If the question gets deleted, all votes disappear anyway along with their respective reputation changes, so it's like it never happened.
>
> But in the meantime, it doesn't hurt anything to vote on closed questions. (In fact, if I were a user with 500 rep, say, and I disagreed with a question's closing, the only action I'd be able to take is upvoting, since I wouldn't have reopen privileges yet.)